# Apple's verification of documents...What they are asking about?

Tags: iphone, ios

I want to register as an IPhone developer(company;s account) so i followed all steps to create it ....  after 3 days i got  following mail
(this is full mail)

> Dear XXXX,
>
> We are currently in the process of
>   reviewing your iOS Developer Program
>   enrollment information. Please fax one
>   of the following forms of identity for
>   your business. To assist   with this
>   process, please ensure your business
>   documents match your enrollment
>   information.
>
> Fax your submission to +1 (408)
>   974-1053. Please include your
>   Enrollment ID  XXXXXXXXXX that was
>   provided to you upon submission.
>
> Please include your main company
>   corporate telephone number with your
>   faxed documents.
>
> Registrar of Companies in the state in
>   which the company is incorporated
>
> Best regards,
>
> Apple Developer Support

I have not understand a line ---- Please fax one of the following forms of identity for your business...what forms they are talking about...
please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a strangely-worded letter, but I'd guess they're asking for your company's Articles of Incorporation as submitted to your state's registrar, or some similar documentation your company has received from your state's registrar indicating your corporate status. Assuming you're in the US.

Comment: Ok i have those documents....but they did not specify that where to write Enrollment ID and phone number ?....

Comment: Just write a note or letter with the information. Or heck, even a fax cover page would probably be fine (though I'd go with a simple letter).

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have applied for the enterprise developer license. You would have to submit your company registration documents and post verification of them by Apple, you'd be given the license. The enrollment number is the number that have been given to you when you filled up the form for license.

Comment: It doesn't look like it's necessarily the enterprise license to me. I know that we had to provide proof of incorporation when signing up our LLC for a normal, non-personal developer account.